# Adding nested json data in terraform resource required attribute

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am quite new to terraform, trying to create an AWS cloudwatch event rule, and it requires event_pattern in string format, on my AWS console it's in json structure.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "cloudwatch_rule" {
    name = "${var.target_env}-cloudfront-rule"
    description = "it will trigger the lambda function."
    event_pattern = "Json data here"
}
```

On AWS via clickops, I have the following rule event-pattern in json format that I want to pass into the terraform resource block, also would like to implement a variable for AWS ARN in the **prefix** area:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.secretsmanager"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutSecretValue", "UpdateSecret", "RestoreSecret", "RotateSecret"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "secretId": [{
        "prefix": $variable here for AWS ARN
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I did some research for using template file, jsonencode, but not sure how to actually implement it.

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heredoc Strings](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#heredoc-strings) in Terraform to have the event_pattern in string format. Within that string you can use [interpolation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#interpolation) to replace the  variable. It would be something like this:

```
variable "prefix_arn" {
   description = "Description..."
   type        = string    
}
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "cloudwatch_rule" {
    name = "${var.target_env}-cloudfront-rule"
    description = "it will trigger the lambda function."
    event_pattern = <<EOT
{
  "source": ["aws.secretsmanager"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutSecretValue", "UpdateSecret", "RestoreSecret", "RotateSecret"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "secretId": [{
        "prefix": ${prefix_arn}
      }]
    }
  }
}
EOT
}
```

*Please note that I've added a variable just for the sake of the example.*